# Get a twitter timeline with only geotagged tweets

Tags: twitter, location, geotagging

What I do need is to get the twitter timeline whith only tweets with location associated.

I know in Facebook it is possible using `me/home?with=location`, is there something like this for twitter?

Answer (score 0):

You can use location in the Search and Streaming API:

- locations for the Streaming API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/streaming-apis/parameters#locations
- geocode for Search API https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/search

Comment: Thank you, but it is a bit more difficult, I have already read the pages you linked me but what I can't do now is to get the timeline with only geotagged tweets.